# Make two SQL Server database checks one check?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Before I start, I should probably mention C# is pretty new to me and I am literally still grabbing the basics.

I have this code written below to check username and password against a SQL Server database. It works and detects if they match or not but I cannot figure out a way to make it one check, running data in both txtLogin and pwdPassword against columns username and passcode.

```
        SqlConnection cnn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = null;
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();

        cnn = new SqlConnection("Server=dbadmin01.database.windows.net;Database=dbadmin;User=info;Password=notGivingThis");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =@TextboxValue", cnn);
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextboxValue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUser.Text;
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(Dt);

        if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //Works - do nothing for now
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username is incorrect!", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

        cnn = new SqlConnection("Server=dbadmin01.database.windows.net;Database=dbadmin;User=info;Password=notGivingThis");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT passcode FROM users WHERE passcode =@PasswordValue", cnn);
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PasswordValue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pwdPassword.Password;
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(Dt);

        if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //Works - Do nothing for now
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect!", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
```

Comment: As an aside, please don't store passwords in plain text. Use a strong hashing algorithm.

Comment: Can you recommend the best way to do this? || "Before I start, I should probably mention C# is pretty new to me and I am literally still grabbing the basics."

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =@TextboxValue AND passcode =@PasswordValue
```

and then add in both parameters before running the query

FYI you don't need to create a new connection for each query.  Connection objects can be reused as long as they aren't in the process of running another query (which is usually not a problem unless you are multithreading or something has gone wrong).  You should also Close connections that you have Opened and Dispose of them (Disposing may close them - check documentation).  Command objects are also IDisposables and should be Disposed.  You can shortcut the need to call Dispose by using the using keyword when you declare the object (thanks @dlatikay for pointing that out in comment below)

Comment: and wrap your connections and commands in `using() { }` blocks, they're `IDisposable`. As currently written, it leaks a connection.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select Username,passcode from users where username =@username",cnn);
```

After you fill the datatable and do the row count check to verify if the username was correct you cant then use

```
if (Dt.Rows[0]["passcode"].ToString()!=pwdPassword.Password)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password");
    return;
}
```

This will do the username check and then the password check at the seperately but using one query.

Alternitively you can use
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select Username,passcode from users where username =@username and password = @Password",cnn);
and then if zero rows are returned then the login failed but you will not know if it is on the username or password